# Find conditional values in a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with individuals with a household id in the first column and their age in the second column:

```
1  32
1  36
1  8
2  50
2  55
3  45
3  40
3  4
3  5
4  23
```

What I want to do is to find the number of persons between certain age classes with a specific household id. An example of some of the age classes are seen below:

```
0
1-2
3
4-6 
7-10
etc
```

So if I search household id `1` I want to find `1` in class 7-10 and when looking for household id `3` I want to find `2` in class 4-6. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`histcounts`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) counts the histogram, and you can input `edges` to it (the edges are the limits of each bin);

Full example on how to do this in 2 lines using your data, and random ranges. The only thing you need to know is that whenever you want a single number as a bin, you just add the edges of the bin very very close to the value itself. In your case they are integers, so -0.1 +0.1 is enough.

```
M=[1  32
1  36
1  8
2  50
2  55
3  45
3  40
3  4
3  5
4  23];
ranges=[-0.1 0.1 1 4 20 30 40]; % random
% separate the matrix into cells with unique IDs
Mcell = arrayfun(@(x) M(M(:,1) == x, :), unique(M(:,1)), 'uniformoutput', false);
% Count bins in each cell
result=cellfun(@(x)(histcounts(x(:,2),ranges)),Mcell,'uniformoutput',false)
```

Comment: I am not sure this works, as it seems it is not possible to specify the bin limits as requested, including bins of zero width (e.g., age class 0).

Comment: Yes, it cannot handel the bins with zero width, which I sadly have in the data. Also, I only want the number bins for a specific household ID and not the data as a whole.

edit: I saw your edit now, that solves one of the problems!

Comment: @KGB91 But separating the array in households IDs is not a problem you have, is it? You can not count "zero width", but you can count "very small width", and if you are with integers, then `[0-1e-3 0+1e-3]` will do the job

Comment: I had both problem: separating the array in households IDs and getting the number of people in each bin. You have solved the latter problem but I also need help with the first one. I think your code is easy and short, which I like since this is a few lines of code in a much bigger application.

Comment: I tried to, but did not find any good solution. Maybe I am just bad at googling...

Comment: There seems to be one more problem that I was not aware of. In the real data the household ID is not growing in a logical way. For instance the data can look like this:

`M=[1 55
1 60
1 18
2 20
2 22
5 50
5 40
5 13]` How can this be solved when trying to find the correct bins with the corresponding ID?

Comment: Solved it by adding:
`familyID = 3;  
AgeOfFamilyMembers = M(find (M== familyID),:)
NumberOfChildrenInAgesClasses = result{1,1}`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is surely a histogram. However, I could not find a build-in function in MATLAB that supports zero-width bins as in your question. Therefore, I wrote a little script on how to compute the desired histogram manually:

```
% the age data
% (first column: id
% second column: age)
mat_data = [1  32
1  36
1  8
2  50
2  55
3  45
3  40
3  4
3  5
4  23];

% the age classes
% (one class per row,
% lower bound in first column,
% upper bound in second column)
age_classes = [0, 0; ...
               1, 2; ...
               3, 3; ...
               4, 6; ...
               7, 10];

% determine all ids
ids = unique(mat_data(:, 1));

% initialize the output matrix
mat_counts = zeros(size(age_classes, 1), length(ids));

% count the number of entries for each id and age class
for idx_id = 1 : length(ids)
    cur_data = mat_data(mat_data(:, 1) == ids(idx_id), 2);
    for idx_age_class = 1 : length(age_classes)
        cur_age_class = age_classes(idx_age_class, :);
        mat_counts(idx_age_class, idx_id) = length(find(cur_data >= cur_age_class(1) & cur_data <= cur_age_class(2)));
    end
end

% plot everything

% create the x-axis labels
xticks = {};
for idx_age_class = 1 : length(age_classes)
    if length(unique(age_classes(idx_age_class, :))) == 1
        xticks{idx_age_class} = num2str(age_classes(idx_age_class, 1));
    else
        xticks{idx_age_class} = sprintf('%.0f-%.0f', age_classes(idx_age_class, 1), age_classes(idx_age_class, 2));
    end
end

figure(1);
bar(mat_counts);
set(gca, 'xticklabel', xticks);
legend(cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(ids)))
xlabel('age class')
ylabel('count')
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I am surprised about this interest with the "zero width". Honestly, just do `[-0.1 0.1]`, he's dealing with integers. No need to overcomplicate the problem

Comment: Seems to work very well, tanks a lot! However I really just want to get the number of each bin for one household ID at a time. How can I tweek the code in order to accomplish this?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I get what you mean, and I see that this is a lot of code to solve a simple problem. However, I am not sure whether it would be more comfortable to use ``histcounts()`` as then the age classes would have to be pre-processed (e.g., -0.1 ... 0.1 etc.) and also the results, as a number of of return bins are not of interest then (e.g., the one with limits 
 0.1 ... 1) and the relevant bins have to be selected.

Comment: @KGB91 I'm glad this works for you. If I understand you correctly and you want the individual histograms for each household: they correspond to columns of the ``mat_counts`` matrix. Hence, the counts for household id 1 are in the first column etc.

Comment: @applesoup there are no numbers between 0.1 and 1, the next bin would be the one containing the number "1". no need of handling cases in the return. Plus in this case, OP already needs to define if the bin is a single number or a range, so it takes an infinitesimal amount of effort to just write `[0.9 1.1]` instead of just `1` and then having a huge code. Plus it obscures greatly what the code does. Don't get me wrong, this is not a bad answer, I just philosophically disagree with this procedure.